# List of docx4j supported XHTML tags

Tags: docx4j

Is there a list to show what XHTML tags and CSS attributes are supported by docx4j XHTML importer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclosure: I wrote the docx4j code in question **

There is no definitive list.  However, there is support for at least:

- p, div, li
- table
- h1 to h3
- table
- img
- span
- a
- br

There is no support for font color right now, nor u (underline).

Support is a 2 phase affair:

- Flying Saucer (XHTMLRenderer) needs to support it

  FS supports pretty much all of CSS 2.1; see [What_XHTML CSS_features_does_Flying_Saucer_currently_support](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/wiki/FAQ#What_XHTML/CSS_features_does_Flying_Saucer_currently_support?)
- docx4j needs to convert the relevant Flying Saucer construct to WordML

If in doubt, just try it on the XHTML of interest to you.